# fabric -ca certificate creation on common storage instead of local machine

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric-ca

It would be grateful if someone helps me out with this. I do wanted to access the certificates and keys from the common storage . if i give the path it is creating a folder near msp and creating the certificates.

I tired by changing the path in docker-compose.yml file. The path changed but it is creating near the msp folder.

I wanted to know , where the default path must be changed.

Comment: Not quite sure what you are trying to do here?   Are you using the fabric-ca-client?  And are you using it on your host system or from within a Docker container?

Comment: Iam using it in dockerised environment. I wanted to store the certificate in another location ,so i want to change the default path.

Comment: So you are running the `fabric-ca-client` in Docker?

Comment: yes running in docker .The certificates generated must be stored in other location than storing it in default location.

Answer (score 0):

`fabric-ca-client` allows you to specify the directory in which keys/certificates will be stored created by using the `-M` option:

`fabric-ca-client enroll -u http://enrollid:enrollsecret@myca:7054 -M /path/to/myfolder`

If you are using Docker to run the `fabric-ca-client` and want to make the key/certs available outside the Docker container, you will need to mount an external volume.

So let's say you want to store the key/certs in the `/var/mycerts` directory on your host system.  You can do:

`docker run --rm -v /var/mycerts:/var/mycerts hyperledger/fabric-ca fabric-ca-client enroll -u http://enrollid:enrollsecret@myca:7054 -M /var/mycerts`

Comment: root@d72f0751d11e:/# fabric-ca-client enroll -u http://enrollid:enrollsecret@localhost:7054 -M /home/work
2019/07/22 11:38:17 [INFO] Created a default configuration file at /etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server/fabric-ca-client-config.yaml
2019/07/22 11:38:17 [INFO] generating key: &{A:ecdsa S:256}
2019/07/22 11:38:17 [INFO] encoded CSR
Error: Response from server: Error Code: 20 - Authentication failure

Comment: Sorry ... make sure you use a real enroll ID and secret (a registered user)

Comment: Thank you so much .We are now able to store the certificates in the different location . Thanks much for your timely help. @Gari Singh

Comment: hi , I do wanted to know why does the user folder created in the path is empty without storing the any value and would like to know regarding the microservices involved?